# Android: Barcode scanning library in a UI View?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

Most apps use ZXing, but all examples of ZXing I've seen use a dedicated full screen activity (whether via intent request or embedded Activity class).  Are there other bar code scanning libraries that encapsulate the barcode scanning in a View object?

If not, what are the components of ZXing I need to extract and/or rebuild?  Can I reuse the CameraManager in my own SurfaceView?  The CaptureActivity does not seem very modular for reuse.

Comment: We did it, but it is a pain and buggy due to the way Android camera preview is handled.  Still haven't fixed the problems on a handful of phones.

Answer (score 0):

MiraSense's Scandit library does this.  I am in talks with their developers to see if it their library does what I need.

Additionally, based on video and in person demo, they have a much better implementation than ZXing.  Much faster and don't rely on the slow autofocus.